# Creating trial number ascending list, for separate subjects in long format data frame, R?

Tags: r

I have a very long data frame (over 300 000 rows), consisting of all subjects trials of a task, in long format. So about 300 rows is successive trials for one subject, followed by the other subjects underneath. What I want to do is create a new column with trial numbers for every subject.

Such as:

`subject   trial_number
    101           1
    101           2
    101           3
    102           1
    102           2
    102           3`

I am thinking I should somehow make R choose a subject number from column *subject*, and then create an ascending list and then loop this over all the subject numbers. But I have not been able to figure out how to loop over subject numbers, while also creating an ascending list in one and the same column over these subjects?

I don't have example code for failed attempts or so, as I haven't been able to figure out how to structure this. I'm thinking some kind of combination of  *subset* and *within*? Or are there better solutions my googling skills haven't helped me find yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and assuming that your initial data frame looks something like `trial_df` below, you can use the following code and the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

# create data frame 
trial_df <- tibble('subject' = c(rep('101', 3), rep('102', 3)),
                  'result' = c(32, 33, 64, 12, 18, 14))

# group by subject and add a row number
# assumes your data frame is ordered by trial number for each subject
new_df <- trial_df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(trial_number = row_number())
```